# How to integrate OpenLayers in WPF application

Tags: wpf, openlayers

I've already succeed to use Open Layers library in ASP.NET application but i don't succeed to integrate it in W PF Application and i don't found examples.

Is it possible? how can i load the map and interact? Is anyone have link or examples?

Best Regards.

Comment: Better use a dedicated map control for WPF, like [Bing Maps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bing/wpf-control/hh750210(v%3Dmsdn.10)), or some open source alternative.

Comment: Ok that's what i did but just wonder if there is a way to use OpenLayers API

Answer (score 0):

It is possible via the WebBrowser Class: [WebBrowser Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.webbrowser?view=netframework-4.7.2)